# NSClipView bounds - Problems to find out the scroll position

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview

I try to find out, when the user scrolls to the end of a `NSTableView`. So of course, the tableview is embedded as usual in a `NSClipView` an this is embedded in a `NSScrollView`. There are no more changes except the fact of adding insets to the ClipView (Top: 20, Left/Right: 20, Bottom: 0).

To get notified about the scrolling, I connected an outlet of the `NSClipView`.

So I use this code:

```
self.clipView.postsBoundsChangedNotifications = true
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(scrollViewDidScroll(notification:)),
                                       name: NSView.boundsDidChangeNotification,
                                       object: self.clipView)

...

@objc func scrollViewDidScroll(notification: Notification) {
    print("\(self.clipView.contentInsets.bottom) - \(self.clipView.contentInsets.top)")
    print(self.clipView.bounds)
}
```

If I'm at the top of the ScrollView, the print-results look like this:

```
0.0 - 20.0
(-20.0, -20.0, 600.0, 556.0)
// x      y    width  height
```

This seems ok for me. But if I'm at the bottom, it looks like this:

```
0.0 - 20.0
(-20.0, 595.0, 600.0, 556.0)
```

In my understanding, the y-value should be 536, not 595. Where is this difference coming from?

Comment: What is `tableView.frame.size.height`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by my one by observing the different values especially after resizing the window. So:

`clipView.documentVisibleRect` is that, what you really can see. Of course I cannot use the height value of this part. The origin value tells me about the position in the ScrollView.

So necessary is the height of the total content. Therefore I have to use `clipView.documentRect`.

Now it's very easy: If the visibleRects y-position + the height of the visible rect is the same as the height of the total clipview, we are at the end. This code works:

```
@objc func scrollViewDidScroll(notification: Notification) {
    let scrollY = self.clipView.documentVisibleRect.origin.y
    let visibleHeight = self.clipView.documentVisibleRect.size.height
    let totalHeight = self.clipView.documentRect.size.height

    if scrollY + visibleHeight >= totalHeight {
        print("end")
    }
}
```